# ¿Por qué las propiedades de mi clase se muestran como indefinidas después de asignarles un valor a través de una función en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

Estoy tratando de crear un servicio en Angular que a su vez utiliza  el servicio geocode para obtener la posición actual, si el resultado es exitoso se ejecuta una función que extrae únicamente la longitud y la latitud y los asigna a las propiedades latitud y longitud de la clase, hasta ese punto todo pareciera estar funcionando pero cuando trato de leer esos valores desde cualquier otra parte de la clase o desde un componente el resultado devuelto por esas variables es **undefined**, a continuación les dejo el código a ver si alguien tiene idea de como puedo hacer para que las variables latitud y longitud mantengan el valor que se les ha asignado en la función setValues y que dicho valor pueda ser usado en otra función o desde un componente. De antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar, saludos

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrentPositionService {

  public latitude: number
  public longitude: number

  constructor() {
    this.getCurrentLocation()
    console.log(this.latitude)
  }

  public getCurrentLocation() {
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.setValues(position) 
      }); 
    }
  }

  public setValues(position: Position){
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude
    console.log(this.latitude)   
  }

}
```

Comment: yo creo que esto se debe al `callback` que le pasas a `getCurrentPosition` si el usuario deniega los permisos para acceder la unbicación eso ya no se ejecuta. Creo con tener una variable auxiliar en el servicio que indique si se ha ejecutado el callaback o no y cuando en otro componente hagas el get de las coordenadas validar si se ha ejecutado el callback y se han seteado los valores.

Comment: Tu codigo funciona correctamente. Lo que puede pasar es que tengas deshabilidato la localizacion del navegador. Posiblemente, funcione bien solo en chrome. [Aqui tu codigo funcionado](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vebqwm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Solo necesitas abrirlo en `open in new window` en la parte derecha superior.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por responder, el problema finalmente era de asincronía, y se pudo resolver implementando una promesa, en el siguiente vínculo está la solución https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Angular/1746542-Scope-en-Angular.html#last